# Example of Line at infinity in Miles' Book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

> *Background*:
> I've started reading Miles' "Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry" ([Link](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/Miles.Reid/MA4A5/UAG.pdf)) recently though struggling a lot. \

Please allow me to just paste the example on Page 23 as follows;
[image]

I have visualised each example as follows;

- (a): https://www.geogebra.org/3d/mfek26ph
- (b): https://www.geogebra.org/3d/z5uxh9e6

In both cases, the intersection points (e.g., $(a, \pm b, 0), (0, 1, 0)$) are the projective coordinates, i.e.,, points along a ray can be representative by a point, right?

Comment: What you've graphed there is the *affine cone* over the corresponding projective variety. As you said, to appropriately visualize these points in the affine cone, we would need to graph instead the affine cone of the points: the lines connecting them to the origin. [Here is the right modification](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/harm6enz) for your first graph.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for your answer and for your modification!
Sorry, I think I shouldn've used a point in the visualisation! What I meant by the point was that they are representatives of other points along the ray from the origin!
So I think I'm on the same page as you...?

Btw, `Affine cone` is a new concept to me... so could you elaborate my mistake a little more...?
Thank you!

Comment: If $S \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is a subset, where $\mathbb{P}^n$ is viewed as the set of lines through the origin in $k^{n + 1}$, the *affine cone over $S$* is defined to be the union $C(S) = \bigcup_{\ell \in S} \ell \subset k^{n + 1}$.